# Using p4 api to submit individual files of changelist

Tags: c#, perforce, changelist

Using P4V GUI, you can expand a changelist, right click any file in that changelist, and submit that file individually.  Using the p4 api, all the functionality I seem to have is the ability to submit a whole changelist (using Changelist.Submit).  Is there a way to submit a particular file in a changelist using the p4 api?

I realize there are probably ways around this, such as creating a new changelist and using the P4Command "reopen" to move a file there and then submitting this changelist, but I feel like there is a more succinct, quality way to go about this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Under the covers, P4V is doing precisely what you describe: "creating a new changelist and using the P4Command "reopen" to move a file there and then submitting this changelist".

You can do all these steps using the p4 command line or the programmatic APIs, but the overall process is still the same.